# Playwright Python gives inconsistent scraping results

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

My Playwright Python script goes to LeetCode problems url, Selects "Top 100 Liked Questions", scraps all the "Problem names" and goes to "Next page" until "Next page" button is disabled and keeps printing out the "Problem names".

The problem is that Sometimes on Page 2, I get Page 1's problems names, sometimes I get empty results, and sometimes I get all of the correct results(when I put slow_mo=1000).

Here's the code

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    count = 1 #Page Count
    browser = p.chromium.launch(slow_mo=1000)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/")
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Lists").click()
    page.get_by_text("Top 100 Liked Questions").click()
    while True:
        print(f'\nPage {count}\n')
        count += 1 #Increment Page Count

        #Current Page Operations
        nodes = page.query_selector_all("a.h-5")
        for node in nodes:
            print(node.inner_text())

        #Next Page
        if(page.get_by_label("next", exact=True).is_enabled() == True):
            page.get_by_label("next", exact=True).click()
        else:
            break
    
    browser.close()
```

when you go to the url manually, and select Top 100 Liked questions, there are 2 pages only and both have the 100 top liked problems.

My script somehow sometimes returns empty, sometimes returns page 1's problems again on page 2, the results are very inconsistent, when I add slow_mo=1000 then the errors are less frequent but still they appear.

How do I ensure accurate results 100% of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that each click triggers a navigation, but instead of waiting for the navigation to resolve, your `while` loop immediately starts the next iteration and begins pulling down the data regardless of whether it's been updated or not. This can cause results to appear twice and/or not appear at all if the next chunk loads too slowly.

Using [locators](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-locator) over query selectors is preferred, but not enough to determine when the page has changed. You could [wait for the URL to change](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/navigations#waiting-for-navigation), or wait until your current/last page's worth of results changes, since it's a pretty safe assumption that each page's results are unique.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.37.0


with sync_playwright() as p:
    def scrape_problems():
        loc = page.locator('[role="rowgroup"] [href^="/problems/"]')
        loc.first.wait_for()
        problems = [x for x in loc.all_text_contents() if x]

        if len(problems) == 51:
            problems.pop(0) # get rid of the "daily" problem

        return problems

    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/")
    problems = []
    chunk = scrape_problems()
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Lists").click()
    page.get_by_text("Top 100 Liked Questions").click()

    while True:
        # caution: no timeout/retry limit on this loop
        while (next_chunk := scrape_problems()) == chunk:
            pass

        problems.extend(chunk := next_chunk)

        if page.get_by_label("next", exact=True).is_enabled():
            page.get_by_label("next", exact=True).click()
        else:
            break

    for p in problems:
        print(p)

    print("count:", len(problems))
    browser.close()
```

Note that "Top 100 Liked Questions" only has 100 results, so you could click on the "100 / page" dropdown and skip pagination entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.

I understand the problem is with the Loop not waiting for the next page to completely load.

And your piece of code in proposed solution is insightful, However it didn't work as intended. It's still printing the same Page 1's problems again.

Even tho we have "while (next_chunk := scrape_problems()) == chunk:" statement there, the problem is the first element "'239. Sliding Window Maximum'," sometimes comes with first scrape_problems(), sometimes not, so it gets out of the while loop even tho the data is old.

Comment: Good call--I thought I tested it, but I must have been having lucky runs. You're right, the problem is the "daily problem" they add to each page showing up and making it seem like the page has changed when it hasn't. Can you try again with the updated code and let me know how it goes? It should filter this problem out more precisely. I ran it probably 20 times and it seems OK, but that's no guarantee. If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll fall back on the URL approach.

Comment: Yes @ggorlen, I commented after I copied pasted your code into my VSCode as it is, and it gave me inaccurate results 9/10 times.
I think you got 20/20 accurate results because the requested url i.e leetcode.com might have server relatively nearer to you and so you get lower latency than me(I live in Pakistan, a South Asian country).

Comment: This is for the updated code or the original code? Latency shouldn't be a factor if it's correctly waiting for the list to change, which I think it should after the update to remove the daily problem.

Comment: Works perfect! 10/10 correct results. I am fairly amateur and maybe this might be stupid to say that the While loop is running for like 20 iterations before it catches the next page chunk(next page loads) and then the loop breaks, I wish there was a more robust solution like after click, it waits for the next page to load completely then run further

Comment: I've suggested [waiting for the URL to change](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url), or using the dropdown to select 100 results per page, which avoids pagination entirely. But polling is pretty common in scraping (that's what [`wait_for_function`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-function-option-polling) does under the hood with `requestAnimationFrame`). What is your main concern with polling the page content? There are potential issues to navigate with the other approaches, too--it's sort of the nature of web scraping.